# Finding probability of picking a higher or lower number card from the deck given an even 13 sided (6 + 8 sided) dice is rolled

Tags: combinatorics

I am designing a game in which a person rolls 2 dice (a 6 sided and a 8 sided). So there are 13 outcomes possible (2 to 14). A person has to then choose a card from the deck and guess whether it is higher or lower than the outcome on the dice. 
If he guesses it right than he gets a point or else he doesn't get a point. What will be the expected value (of points) and probability of winning the game?
Note: 
1) he doesn't get a point if outcome on dice = value of card
2) value of ace is 14

Answer (score 8, accepted):

First, the probabilities of the different outcomes of the dice are:

$P(2)=P(14)=\frac{1}{48}$

$P(3)=P(13)=\frac{2}{48}$

$P(4)=P(12)=\frac{3}{48}$

$P(5)=P(11)=\frac{4}{48}$

$P(6)=P(10)=\frac{5}{48}$

$P(7)=P(8)=P(9)=\frac{6}{48}$

Now, assuming the player plays optimal, the player will say that the card will be higher for the outcomes of 2 through 7, and say it will be lower for the outcomes 9 through 14.  And for the outcome of 8 it doesn't matter which the player picks. Thus, the chances of winning given the different outcomes of the dice are:

$P(W|2)=P(W|14)=\frac{12}{13}$

$P(W|3)=P(W|13)=\frac{11}{13}$

$P(W|4)=P(W|12)=\frac{10}{13}$

$P(W|5)=P(W|11)=\frac{9}{13}$

$P(W|6)=P(W|10)=\frac{8}{13}$

$P(W|7)=P(W|9)=\frac{7}{13}$

$P(W|8)=\frac{6}{13}$

This gives us:

$$P(W)=\sum_{i=2}^{14}(P(i)* P(W|i))=$$

$$\frac{2*1*12+2*2*11+2*3*10+2*4*9+2*5*8+2*6*7+6*6}{48*13}=$$

$$\frac{400}{624}=\boxed{\frac{25}{39}}$$

Comment: (+1) this is what I got as well.

Comment: @robjohn Always nice to have confirmation! :)